# Harmonic function and Neumann Compatibility Condition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

[image]
**______________________________________________________________**
Conversely, in a different approach using Green's 1st identity, I showed that by choosing v ≡ 1, that the compatibility condition is derived, and so if u is harmonic on Ω, then the integral of the normal derivative over the boundary is equal to zero.

[image]
**______________________________________________________________**
**However, for circles/balls lying within the closure of the domain (i.e. intersection with the boundary), do I need to use the mean value principle with Green's theorem to prove that u is a harmonic function in Ω?**

Answer (score 2):

Since [every open set can be expresses as a countable union of open balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299260/union-of-a-countable-collection-of-open-balls) you don't have to deal with intersection of the closure of  an open set $\Omega$ with balls.

Comment: Any other suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: what else do you looking for?

Comment: Ok, so to prove that u is harmonic in Ω, we must show that u satisfies the Laplacian on the boundary.  By the given condition, u and its first two derivatives are continuous in Ω.

Comment: In general, the definition of harmonic function is that applying Laplacian on it you get zero.

Answer (score 1):

To show that u satisfies the Laplacian, we use Green's 1st identity to obtain the inside-outside theorem equality, setting another arbitrary function, v, contained in the same space as u.

Then, we set v = 1 and obtain an new (simplified) expression of Green's first identity. Hence, for an arbitrary circle B lying in Ω closure, with the compatibility condition = 0, then the integral of the Laplacian = 0. Thus, it follows that the Laplacian = 0 and so the second condition of u being harmonic in Ω is satisfied.
[image]