# Is every open and connected set in $\mathbb C$ the continuous image of the open unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, locally-connected

Let
$$
\mathbb D=\{z\in\mathbb C\ |\ |z|<1\}
$$
be the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$. It is well known that an open (nonempty) set $U\subseteq\mathbb C$ is simply connected if and only if it is homeomorphic to the unit disk. One can show that this is equivalent to the fact that there is a continuous **injective** function $f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb C$ such that $f(\mathbb D)=U$.

Therefore, my question is: If $U$ is a (nonempty) open and connected subset of $\mathbb C$, is there always a continuous (but not necessarily injective) function $f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb C$ such that $f(\mathbb D)=U$? It sufficices to assume $U\subseteq\mathbb D$.

If not, how do images of such functions look like?

I know that any compact connected and locally connected subset of $\mathbb C$ is the image of a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ and hence also the image of a continuous function on $\overline{\mathbb D}$. However, the closure of an open and connected set does not have to be locally connected.

I believe that the answer to my first question is negative (although I hope that it is not ;) ).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Not my field, but I'm pretty sure that the answer is positive to your first question. Here's my idea: first project $\Bbb{D}$ to the interval $(-1, 1)$, then expand to $\Bbb{R}$. From there, I'm pretty sure you can use a space-filling curve to fill any disk. Since $U$ is open and connected, it's path connected, and is made up of a countable union of open disks, which we can cover by a single space-filling curve (just join the endpoints for each of the countably many open disks by a path). The result will be heavily non-injective, but I think it works?

Comment: **The Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem:** [A non-empty Hausdorff topological space is a continuous image of the unit interval if and only if it is a compact, connected, locally connected, second-countable space.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#:~:text=The%20Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz%20theorem%20is,connected%2C%20second%2Dcountable%20space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem, as pointed out by Mathlover in the comments, is enough to show my educated guess actually works. In particular, it implies that closed balls in $\Bbb{C}$ are the continuous image of a compact interval. We will need a lemma:

**Lemma** $\quad$ Suppose $\{C_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a countable collection of subspaces of a topological space $X$ (e.g. $\Bbb{C}$) which are continuous images of a compact interval and
$$C := \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty C_n$$
is path-connected. Then $C$ is the continuous image of $[0, \infty)$.

*Proof.* Consider the intervals $I_n := [2n, 2n + 1]$ and $J_n := [2n + 1, 2n + 2]$ for $n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. Let $\mathfrak{i}_n : I_n \to C_n$ be surjective and continuous, and let $\mathfrak{j}_n : J_n \to C$ be a continuous function such that $\mathfrak{j}_n(2n + 1) = \mathfrak{i}_n(2n + 1)$ and $\mathfrak{j}_n(2n + 2) = \mathfrak{i}_{n+1}(2n + 2)$. Then, the map
$$\phi : [0, \infty) = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (I_n \cup J_n) \to C$$
defined by
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} \mathfrak{i}_n(x) & \text{if } \exists n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\} : 2n \le x < 2n + 1 \\ \mathfrak{j}_n(x) & \text{if } \exists n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\} : 2n + 1 \le x < 2n + 2. \end{cases}$$
This function is made up of countably infinitely many continuous pieces, joined at common points, making the function continuous. It's clearly surjective (even just restricting to $\bigcup I_n$), hence $C$ is the continuous image of $[0, \infty)$ under $\phi$. $\square$

Note that every ball in $\Bbb{C}$ is a countable union of closed balls, and recall that [open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$ are a countable union of open balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299260/union-of-a-countable-collection-of-open-balls). Also, in a locally path-connected space, [open and connected implies path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected). Thus, $U$ is the path-connected countable union of closed balls, so by the lemma, it is a continuous image of $[0, \infty)$.

So, to wrap up the proof, as in my comment, simply project the unit disk of $\Bbb{C}$ onto $(-1, 1)$, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$. You can simply keep the map constant for points in $(-\infty, 0]$, and then use $[0, \infty)$ to map continuously onto $U$.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One can prove a stronger claim: given a nonempty open connected $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, there's a *holomorphic* $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\varphi(\mathbb{D})=U$.

First, let $U\neq \mathbb{C},\neq \mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$.  Thanks to the [Riemann uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem), every such open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is hyperbolic, i.e. has $\mathbb{D}$ as its universal cover. Thus there exists a surjective holomorphic map $\mathbb{D}\to U$.
Note that there's a surjective holomorphic map $(\exp(z)+z_0)$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$, and thus it suffices to prove the result for $\mathbb{C}$.
Now, let $f(z)=z^3-1$. It is easy to see that $f:\mathbb{C}-\{1,\exp(2\pi i/3)\}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{C}$.  Precomposing with the covering map $\pi:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}-\{1,\exp(2\pi i/3)\}$, we get the claim.

One can also explore "how much" this function fails to be injective. Indeed, the uniformization theorem implies that, for $U\neq\mathbb{C},U\neq \mathbb{C}-\{z_0\}$, we have $U\simeq \mathbb{D}/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb{D})$ (complex automorphisms) isomorphic to $\pi_1(U)$.
Thus two elements $z_1,z_2$ have the same image iff $\exists \gamma\in \Gamma:\gamma(z_1)=z_2$ (note that with $U$ simply connected we get injectivity).

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you very much!